# Steady flow of the relativistic dust - stress-energy tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, conservation-laws, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Given relativistic dust (p=0) in flat spacetime. The dust moves in one direction along coordinate $x$ only. Consider this flow is steady. So for an observer at rest at fixed point of $x_0$ $v(x_0)$ does not vary with time. Four-velocity is $v^{\alpha}=(\gamma, \gamma v^1 ,0,0)$. The stress-energy tensor is defined as $T^{\alpha \beta}=\rho v^{\alpha}v^{\beta}$ The conservation requires that $\nabla_{\alpha} T^{\alpha \beta}=0$ therefore
$$\partial_{\alpha} T^{\alpha 0}=-\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial (\rho\gamma^2)}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial (\rho \gamma^2 v^1)}{\partial x}=0 \tag{1}$$

$$\partial_{\alpha} T^{\alpha 1}=-\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial (\rho\gamma^2 v^1 )}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial (\rho \gamma^2 (v^1)^2)}{\partial x}=0 \tag{2}$$

If the flow is steady can we neglect first terms in the first equations (1)? 
(In non-relativistic case for a steady flow we would simply have
$div(\rho v)=0$) Then the first term in equation (2) should also be identically zero leaving just
$$\frac{\partial (\rho \gamma^2 v^1)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial (\rho \gamma^2 (v^1)^2)}{\partial x}=0 \tag{3}$$
Edit added:
One of possible approach to look at the relativistic continuity equation is to consider comoving with a fluid/dust (Eulerian) frame of reference. In such frame the stress-energy tensor has diagonal form (ref. Landau-Lifshiz) or in the case of dust it has one non zero component which is $T^{0 0}=\rho c^2$ and $T^{\alpha \beta}=0$ if $\alpha =\beta \neq 0$. In comoving frame of reference the density is constant $\rho=const$ therefore the continuity equation requires that $$ \rho \: div(\gamma \: v^1)= 0 \tag{4}$$ then it is still not in agreement with (3).

Comment: Seems to be correct though.. Just need some experts to look through.

Comment: Shouldn't the four-velocity be $v^\alpha=(\gamma,\gamma v^1,0,0)$
instead of $(\gamma,v^1,0,0)$ ?

Comment: Corrected, thanks

Comment: The resulting expression looks really contradictory.

Comment: Seems like a bit of a stretch to tag this as 'fluid dynamics'. It's very far from what would be considered mainstream classical fluids.

Comment: Well, is fluid dynamics non-relativistic only?

Comment: Added comments with divergence, does it look more hydtrodynamic-like then? )

Comment: I wouldn't really consider 'dust' a fluid either. It seems like more of a dispersed particulate than a continuous fluid.

Comment: I agree. It is pressure-less. I am looking for the conservation and use-case of stress-energy tensor then. Thanks

Comment: Since there is no answer I see only 2 possibilities:
1.  wrong question or
2. stress-energy tensor is useles (at least for such case)